# ¿Por qué lo siguiente funciona?

Tags: javascript

Revisando los tutoriales de *w3schools*, me topé con la siguiente línea de código, la cual compara si dos objetos llegan a chocar dentro de un `canvas` y si lo hacen regresa **verdadero.**

```
var crash = true;

if(mybottom < othertop || mytop > otherbottom || myrigth < otherleft || myleft > otherrigth) crash = false;

return crash;
```

El código funciona, pero no logro entender por qué. Se supone que si una de las condiciones del `if` se cumple, entonces `crash`, siempre debería ser **falso**, pero con solo que una de las condiciones sea **falsa**, `crash` sigue siendo **verdadero**.

Quisiera saber qué está sucediendo y por qué.

Comment: Respuesta: **no puede ser verdadero** si se cumple una de las 4 condiciones.

Comment: Esto no es un problema de javascript, es un problema de algoritmo o de logica

Answer (score 3):

Tu lógica es correcta, lo que pasa es que ninguna condición se cumple y por ende el valor de `crash` no cambia, por lo que devuelve `true`.

Tu duda entonces es sobre la lógica utilizada para determinar si los objetos chocan, la cual podría leerse así:

1. `mybottom < othertop`:

¿La base de mi objeto está más arriba que el límite superior del otro objeto?

2. `mytop > otherbottom`:

¿El límite superior de mi objeto está más abajo que la base del otro objeto?

3. `myrigth < otherleft`:

¿El lado derecho de mi objeto está antes del lado izquierdo del otro objeto?

4. `myleft > otherrigth`:

¿El lado izquierdo de mi objeto está después que el lado derecho del otro objeto?

Para entender mejor considera que la coordenada `0:0` en el *canvas* es **arriba a la izquierda**, entonces moverse hacia la derecha es **mayor** en el eje horizontal y moverse hacia abajo es **mayor** en el eje verical.

Comment: Gracias, si lo describes de esa manera se ve mas simple de entender. Solo para aclarar, si tengo mi objeto a la izquierda de otro objeto, cuando entre en el **if** entonces todas las condiciones con excepción de `myrigth < otherleft` serán falsas, pero en caso de que el lado derecho de mi objeto toque el lado izquierdo del otro objeto las 4 condiciones se volverían falsas y crash seguiría siendo true. Estoy en lo correcto?

Comment: @Wove Es correcto! De hecho mi lógica estaba al revés, pero ya la he corregido; checa la respuesta actualizada, creo que quedó más clara.

Answer (score 1):

Esto significa que hay 4 condiciones.

1. `mybottom < othertop`
2. `mytop > otherbottom`
3. `myrigth < otherleft`
4. `myleft > otherrigth`

- La sentencia `mybottom < othertop` significa que `mybottom` es menor a `othertop`.
- La sentencia `mytop > otherbottom` significa que `mytop` es mayor a `otherbottom`.

Si se cumple alguna de las 4 condiciones, devuelve `false`. De lo contrario, devuelve el valor inicial, que es `true`.